# Automatic Timestamp when a Cell on the same row gets Updated and count the entry of specefic date

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the link of my google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSE2Yib_anFI3VZDb3DKBoxvhP8ONqCkzyzCfomdq4Y/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to make a patient management sheet.

When I enter the ID of the patient in "PATIENT FOLLOWUP" sheet, some information is imported from 'DATA ENTRY' sheet. I want a date to be automatically stamped when I enter this new entry. I don't want it also changes the date of previous visit, for example, as I have tried with formulas.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with Apps Script.

#### Instructions

1. In your spreadsheet, go to the menu above, click "Tools" then "Script Editor"
2. In the Script Editor, delete the text that is there and paste in the following code:

   ```
   function onEdit(e) {
     if (e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.range.getValue()) {
       var currentRow = e.range.getRow()

       if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "PATIENT FOLLOWUP") {
         var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet()
         var dateRange = ss.getRange(currentRow, 6)
         dateRange.setValue(new Date())
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Save the script and go back to your spreadsheet and test.

---

#### Explanation

- Every time you edit your spreadsheet the script will run.
- It will check if the edit is made in column 2, where the patient ID is.
- It will check that the edit is in the sheet "PATIENT FOLLOWUP".
- It will check that the edit is not just deleting a value.
- It will get the row which the change was made.
- It will insert a new date in column 6 (Date)

---

**WARNING** If you edit an ID it will **REPLACE** the date.

---

#### References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app